# rails-5 active_job sidekiq unable to push/add a job directly into a redis named queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I trying to add a job directly into redis and it is throwing the error below:

```
  WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
  2018-11-03T00:45:14.826Z 31 TID-gst0yl4s0 WARN: 
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-5.0.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:233:in `      constantize'
```

This is the command I am running:

```
msg = {
   arguments: [{
     '_aj_globalid' =>  'gid://app-name/Article/25'
   },
   [{name: 'jamis'}]
 ],
   'job_class' => 'ImporterJob',
   'job_id' => SecureRandom.uuid,
   'queue_name' => 'importer_job'
 }

 redis.lpush("queue:importer_job", JSON.dump(msg) )
```

This fails and the next attempt shown below also fails:

```
 msg = {
   args: [{
     arguments: [{
       '_aj_globalid' =>  'gid://app-name/Article/25'
     },
     [{name: 'jamis'}]
   ],
     'job_class' => ImporterJob,
     'job_id' => SecureRandom.uuid,
     'queue_name' => 'importer_job'
   }]
 }

redis.lpush("queue:importer_job", JSON.dump(msg) )
```

I have tried it with the both of the job classes below and get thesame error:

```
class ImporterJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :importer_job
  def perform(data)
    puts "datis #{data}"
  end
end
```

This uses a regular sidekiq worker

```
class ImporterJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'importer_job'

  def perform(data)
    puts "datis #{data}" 
  end
end

msg = { "class" => 'UbiquityCsvImporterJob',
"queue" => 'ubiquity_csv',
"args" => values,
'retry' => true,
'jid' => SecureRandom.hex(12),
'created_at' => Time.now.to_f,
'enqueued_at' => Time.now.to_f }
```

Comment: Why are you using that hash to push to redis? Because on the code I see it expects a "job_hash" with a key "class" https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb#L133. Also check the Client class, it shows a "queue" key too https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/client.rb#L217. I'm not sure where you got that hash from, but it looks wrong.

Comment: thanks @arieljuod I have updated the data that is pushed into redis using the second link in your comment but it is still now working. I will try a few things and see.